# Cost of using functions in fortran (or any other language)

Tags: fortran, fortran95

Let say I have a array which is very big `verybigvariable`

And I have defined a function that does some operations like this

```
function myfunc(var) result(res)
real:: var(:,:,:),res

...
...
...

end function myfunc
```

My question is that when I call this function like this

```
myvar=myfunc(verybigvariable)
```

what happens? does it duplicate my variable so it holds 2X space in the ram during the execution of the function? If so how can I prevent this? (In a simple program, I know, I can define the function without any parameter and make it use existing variables, but If I am programming a module, it seems I have to include parameter to the definition)

Comment: I can only speak for C, but in C, parameters are always copied. You can resolve this is C by using pointers, which have a fixed, small size for each system. Also, in C, an array is passed as a pointer by default, but again, I can't speak for fortran.

Comment: Thx, It is probably the same in any language or most of them. I will learn about pointers.

Comment: Oh, that "auto pointer" functionality for arrays is very nice. I hope fortran has that too.

Comment: I just found something interesting. While googling for "fortran pointers", the first hit said: "As you may recall Fortran passes a function the address of an argument...", so in fortran, it would seem that parameters are always passed using pointers.

Comment: @antonijn Awsome! please post this as an answer so that anyone can reach the solution and also I can reward it :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Fortran language standard does not specify how arguments are passed.  Typically in the interest of efficiency the compiler will not make a copy but pass the address of the argument.  There will be cases in which a Fortran compiler has to make a copy.   E.g., the actual argument is a non-contiguous array but the procedure expects a contiguous argument.  The compiler will have to fix the mismatch by making a copy that is contiguous  to pass to the procedure.  If the procedure modifies that argument, the values have to be copied back to the original argument.

Answer (score 0):

In fortran it [seems](http://www.personal.psu.edu/jhm/f90/lectures/42.html) that parameters are passed by reference. This means that only the **address** of the variable is passed, and the function can then access the variable through that address.

So no, the array is not copied, only the address of the array is passed. The overhead for this will be either 32 bits for a 32-bit system, or 64 bits for a 64-bit system.

I have no experience with fortran, and this is only what I could figure out though a Google search, so if any Fortran programmers have any remarks, please feel free to edit/comment.